# Move Flickable/ListView using Slider QML

Tags: qt, slider, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I need to scroll a `Flickable/ListView` using a `Slider` rather than a `scrollbar`, If I use a `ScrollBar` everything works perfect but I need a visual experience like a `slider`(A round handle and a path line). As In vertical scrollBar we can't set `height` of the handle and in the horizontal scrollbar, we can't set `width` of the handle. Due to this limitation, I used the `slider` itself to scroll a `Flickable/ListView`. Following is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    id:window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Flickable{
        id:flick
        width : parent.width * 0.70
        height : parent.height * 0.70

        contentWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width
        contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
        contentX:(contentWidth - width) * horSlider.position
        contentY:(contentHeight-height) * verSlider.position
        clip:true

        Grid{
            id:grid
            columns: 5
            spacing:50
            Repeater{
                id:rept
                model:20
                Button{
                    width: 100
                    height : 100
                    text:"Btn "+index
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Slider{
        id:horSlider
        anchors.top:flick.bottom
        anchors.left:flick.left
        anchors.right:flick.right
    }

    Slider{
        id:verSlider
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        anchors.top:flick.top
        anchors.bottom:flick.bottom
        anchors.left:flick.right

        rotation: 180
    }
}
```

1) If I move the `sliders` `Flickable` is moving as expected but if `Interactive` flag is enabled then how to move the sliders if user flicks with the fingers rather than using `sliders`?

2) Is there any way to design a `scrollBar` similar to `Slider` (A round handle with a path Line)?

Comment: Search this site, how to create bidirectional bindings. You can also have a smaller indicator inside the scrollbar handle, that moves within the scrollbar handle according to the position of the flickable.

Comment: @derM Can you please tell me which site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example how to connect `Flickable` and `Slider`s together. Notice that vertical slider's handle is at the bottom when the position is 0, so you need to invert the position.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 360
    height: 360
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent

        contentWidth: dummyContent.width
        contentHeight: dummyContent.height

        Text {
            id: dummyContent
            text: "ABC"
            color: "red"
            font.pixelSize: 512
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: hslider
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: vslider.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        value: flickable.contentX / (flickable.contentWidth - flickable.width)

        Binding {
            target: flickable
            property: "contentX"
            value: hslider.position * (flickable.contentWidth - flickable.width)
            when: hslider.pressed
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: vslider
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: hslider.top

        value: 1.0 - (flickable.contentY / (flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height))

        Binding {
            target: flickable
            property: "contentY"
            value: (1.0 - vslider.position) * (flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height)
            when: vslider.pressed
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]